# Python multiprocessing returning AttributeError when following documentation code

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-3.6

I decided to try and get into the multiprocessor module to help speed up my program. To figure it out, I tried using some of the code examples on the official python documentation on multiprocessing.

## First attempt: [Introduction](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#introduction)

```
>>> from multiprocessing import Pool
>>>
>>> def f(x):
...     return x*x
...
>>> if __name__ == '__main__':
...     with Pool(5) as p:
...         print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
...
Process SpawnPoolWorker-3:
Process SpawnPoolWorker-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 108, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 337, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'f' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 108, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 337, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'f' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
Process SpawnPoolWorker-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 108, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 337, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'f' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

Here I assume that the pool function is broken; maybe there is a typo somewhere in the lastest version. So I try some of the more specific code.

## Second attempt: [Process class code block 2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class)

```
>>> from multiprocessing import Process
>>> import os
>>>
>>> def info(title):
...     print(title)
...     print('module name:', __name__)
...     print('parent process:', os.getppid())
...     print('process id:', os.getpid())
...
>>> def f(name):
...     info('function f')
...     print('hello', name)
...
>>> if __name__ == '__main__':
...     info('main line')
...     p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
...     p.start()
...     p.join()
...
main line
module name: __main__
parent process: 43824
process id: 54888
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'f' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

At this point I know the underlying error is with the Process function of multiprocessing. However, I think that the extended code might have broken something, so I try the simple code.

## Third Attempt [Process class code block 1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class)

```
>>> from multiprocessing import Process
>>>
>>> def f(name):
...     print('hello', name)
...
>>> if __name__ == '__main__':
...     p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
...     p.start()
...     p.join()
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'f' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

At this point I was desperate. I think that maybe the argument was messing with the Process class.

## Final attempt: self-generated code

```
>>> from multiprocessing import Process
>>>
>>> def f():
...     print('hello')
...
>>> if __name__ == '__main__':
...     p = Process(target=f)
...     p.start()
...     p.join()
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'f' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

Now I am totally confused because I do not know why the error is occuring. Could someone help me figure out why I am getting this error every time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're in interactive mode. That basically doesn't work with `multiprocessing`, because the workers have to import `__main__` and get something that mostly resembles the main process's `__main__`. This is one of the many ways in which the `multiprocessing` API is horribly confusing.

Put your code in a script and run the script.

Comment: the sample code works fine on unixlike platforms -- the OP's issue is a windows-specific quirk

Comment: thank you. once i put it into a script file it worked perfectly

Answer (score 5):

When `multiprocessing` is invoked on windows, it uses the [`spawn`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) strategy for creating new processes.

> The parent process starts a fresh python interpreter process.

The *rough* strategy taken here for function objects that are "pickled" across processes is:

1. Record the module of the function before creating a new process (in this case `f.__module__` => `__main__`)
2. Encode that to some representation
3. In the newly spawned process, initialize the main module (for interactive execution this is an empty module)
4. "unpickle" the arguments, for functions this means:

   1. import their module
   2. access their function name from that module (where you're getting your `AttributeError`)

In your case this looks roughly like this:

1. Record `('__main__', 'f')`
2. encode that
3. spawn a new process, initialize an empty `__main__` module
4. unpickle (recover `__main__` and `f`)

   1. `import __main__ as mod`
   2. `obj = getattr(mod, 'f')` (boom!)

For more details about the specific pickling / unpickling, check out the [`ForkingPickler`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bd73e72b4a9f019be514954b1d40e64dc3a5e81c/Lib/multiprocessing/reduction.py#L198-L223)

Here's an excerpt:

```
#
# Try making some callable types picklable
#

def _reduce_method(m):
    if m.__self__ is None:
        return getattr, (m.__class__, m.__func__.__name__)
    else:
        return getattr, (m.__self__, m.__func__.__name__)
class _C:
    def f(self):
        pass
register(type(_C().f), _reduce_method)


def _reduce_method_descriptor(m):
    return getattr, (m.__objclass__, m.__name__)
register(type(list.append), _reduce_method_descriptor)
register(type(int.__add__), _reduce_method_descriptor)
```

The fix is to put your code into an actual module such that when that is re-initialized on the other side it can import it.