# multiprocessing can't call target function

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I tried running a simple multiprocessing script but it doesn't seem to work

```
import multiprocessing
import time

start = time.perf_counter()

def run():
    print('sleeping for 1 second')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('done sleeping')

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=run)
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=run)

p1.start()
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()

finish = time.perf_counter()

print(f'Finished in {round(finish-start, 2)} second(s)')
```

The error message says

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'run' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

(more than that)

Comment: Are you sure this is all the code you have? I ran it myself, and it seems to be working.

Comment: whats your command to run this ?

Comment: Possibly either [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385708/multiprocessing-example-giving-attributeerror) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48593694/python-multiprocessing-returning-attributeerror-when-following-documentation-cod) might help.

Comment: Yea this is all my code

Comment: I tried running it in an ide and python, still doesn't work

Comment: As @sj95126 suggested, put function `run` in some other file such as *worker.py* and then `from worker import run`.